# Why M$\otimes$N can be considered as a domain for a Linear Map but M $\times$ N is a domain of Bilinear Maps?

Tags: tensor-products

In one of the [lecture notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013-c5.pdf), I have read that:

> Instead of bilinear maps
> from M $\times$ N we can then always consider linear maps from the tensor product, and thus use all the machinery that we have developed so far for homomorphism.

I can't see why M$\otimes$N can be considered as a domain for a Linear Map but M $\times$ N is a domain of Bilinear Maps?

Comment: Why the downvote if someone asks a question to remove any confusion?

Comment: No idea, thay can have done it since you are writing a space is a linear map. I do not agree but some people may not like it. Try to edit and I'll give my vote to compensate

Comment: Also helpful would be a little bit more context. Did you have tensor products of vector spaces already? Which definition are you using? Have you seen the universal property already? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I only dealt with tensor products of matrices.

Comment: All right. The problem then is that your linked text says " $M\otimes N$ for given $R$-modules $M$ and $N$", so $M,N$ are not matrices. Then it would be better to read first about the tensor product before posting this question, because any answer would need to assume this, i.e., that you worked a bit yourself before. The first case would be the case of vector spaces, i.e., the ring $R$ is a field.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a bit of notation: *a space cannot be a linear map*.

A tensor product is a vector space, hence you can consider linear maps having it as the domain. Do not confuse maps having it as domain, and its elements.